# Gallery app: Fetch URLs from json API, then fetch each image from URLs

Tags: java, android, okhttp, android-glide

I'm trying to make a gallery app. It should fetch images one by one and display it in a RecyclerView. The source is a json feed https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1&tags=cat

**[1]** it should download the links from media field and then **[2]** download the image

This has to be done asynchronously and outside of the UI thread

How should I go about this, and what library should I use?

I know about `Glide` but it doesn't seem to handle the first task

I tried `OkHttp` but for some reason half or more of the images failed to load. `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());` complains that the the stream is null. The image link is correct, but either  `OkHttp` or `BitmapFactory` do not support these images for some reason.

I also tried `AsyncTask` to some success but it is deprecated and I'm currently using a Thread class instead

The solution is probably a mix of two but I'm lost

Comment: Coroutines + Coil?

Comment: @DarShan I modified the question to show that I'm using java. I'll check those out still.

Comment: You can use Retrofit for fetching images from your json api

Comment: @VishalBeep as in fetching the links, or also downloading the images?

Comment: You can may check this article [Download Image From URL in Android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/download-image-from-url-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with Volley for downloading the image links from the Flickr Feed.

I then used Glide to load the image into my RecyclerView once the links are obtained.

For some reason, both BitmapFactory.decodeStream() an even Picasso failed to load many of the images that Glide loaded without issue. I'm still not sure why.